# Help needed for developing iPhone application

Tags: iphone, configuration

I have following system configuration:

```
MAC OS X (10.5.8)
XCode (3.1.4)
iOS (3.0)
```

1) Can i develop application for iPhone 4 with this configuration?

2) If not then what are the basic system requirement for developing application for both iPhone 3 and iPhone 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per apple -

> To install Xcode 4, you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard.

Comment: to finish that -  Xcode 3.2 requires an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 
version 10.6.6 or later

Comment: can i develop iPhone 4 application with the configuration as given in my question?

Comment: @Sukhi if you read the answers you've been given, and the docs I linked to you'd know the answer to your question

Comment: 'MAC OS X (10.5.8)' is your conf, I stated in my answer you need 10.6.6 minimum . therefore the answer given to your question speaks for itself. sorry - time for a new mac mini, or mac book pro :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: actually i am new to iPhone development.i already tried but didn't get satisfactory answer.